# How to insert to collection of a parent class using EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have EF Code first setup where an **Account can have many transactions** in it.

```
public class Account : BaseEntity
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountTitle { get; set; }
    public decimal CurrentBalance { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public AccountStatus AccountStatus { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
public enum AccountStatus
{
    Active = 0,
    InActive = 1
}
```

and Transaction is setup like this.

```
 public class Transaction : BaseEntity
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
public enum TransactionType
{
    Deposit = 0,
    Withdraw = 1
}
```

generic repo implementation of Add method is like this

```
public  TEntity Add(TEntity t)
    {           
            t.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            DbSet.Add(t);
            return t;                                
    }
```

i have a generic repository implemented using unit of work as well.

in the services layer i am adding the transaction like this

```
 public async Task<Transaction> AddTransaction(Transaction transaction, string accountId)
    {
       // var account = await _unitOfWork.AccountRepository.GetAsync(accountId);
        // transaction.Account = account;
        var result =  _unitOfWork.TransactionRepositoy.Add(transaction);
        await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
        return result;
    }
```

CommitAsync is just calling _context.SaveChangesAsync();

when i am adding the Transaction how to tell which Account i am adding it for ?
Because as mentioned above. Account can have many Transactions (ICollection) and Transaction belongs to an Account (Navigation Property Account).

Comment: Am I missing “Attach”? If yes than how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is up to you to decide which Account to add the transaction to. The
> **accountId** parameter here should be the Account you need to add.

**And i think the two lines you commented out are just what you need**.

First of all, *`the accountId you pass represents the data of the Account that the transaction needs to be associated with`*, and make sure that the Account table contains this accountId data.

Obtain the Account data from the database according to the accountId, and then assign it to the *Transaction's Account field* to save it.

Common efcore implementation code:

```
   public async Task<Transaction> AddTransaction(Transaction transaction, string accountId)
    {
        transaction.Account = _context.Account.Find(accountId)
         _context.Transaction.Add(transaction);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); 
        return transaction;
    }
```